# Powerlaw python get the scaling constant

Tags: python, power-law

I've been recently trying to fit a power law distribution to my data using the Powerlaw package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/powerlaw). My goal is to obtain equation in form f(x) = Cx^{-alpha}.

Following the instructions:

```
fit = powerlaw.Fit(data, xmin = 230.0, discrete = True)

fit.power_law.alpha
```

In fact return the alpha coefficient, but what about the C, a normalization constant? Is there a way to compute it directly?

Is it possible, that C = sum (data)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The constant could be anything as the power law gives you a distribution which is proportional.

Comment: I don't think I understand. In articles, there is always a constant, where would they have gotten it from?